# Как редактировать слайдер в MODX?

Tags: html5, css3, cms, modx

Необходимо редактировать слайдер на MODX, с этим движком сталкиваюсь впервые.
Как можно редактировать слайдер через MODX? Если редактировать слайдер через админ панель, то куда нужно заходить? Или если через `FTP-клиент`в какой корневой папке искать?

Answer (score 2):

Все ребята в целом правильно пишут. ***Я бы сделал так:***

1. Зашел бы внутри админки на страницу, где есть слайдер.

---

2. Возможно там подключена галерея и вы в закладках настройки ресурса (этой страницы) сможете отредактировать сами слайды. Либо в самом верхнем меню админки есть пункт "Приложения" и там в выпадающем списке будет что-то похожее на ваш слайдер или галерею, перейдя туда скорее всего можно будет отредактировать слайды и их группы, можно будет сделать настройки.

---

3. Если нужно поправить сам шаблон слайдера, то посмотрел бы в текст ресурса (контентная часть), если он включен в режиме кода, то там может быть вызов наподобие [[slider? tpl=`tpl.slider`]], так вот в данном случае tpl.slider будет названием Чанка с содержимым кода слайдера.

---

4. Если там ничего полезного нет, то посмотрел бы название шаблона, используемого на странице и перешел бы в "Элементы" в левом древовидном меню и там бы нашел шаблон, а уже в коде шаблоны искал бы вызов слайдера аналогично пункту 3.

---

5. Когда нашел бы вызов слайдера, то там и нашел бы название шаблона. Далее там же в древовидном меню, но уже в разделе чанков нашел бы нужный шаблон, который уже можно отредактировать. Вызов слайдера может сопровождаться вызовов нескольких чанков, один для обёртки, другой для содержимого, имейте в виду.

---

**Сам слайдер - это сниппет- PHP код, который использует для вывода на страницу чанки в качестве своих шаблонов. Они все носят похожие и логичные имена вроде Slider.**

Если слайдер особенно сложный, то у него могут быть настройки как в файловой системе, так и в настройках системы.

Файлы самих слайдов или дополнительные скрипты вы можете поискать в разделе "Файлы" в левом древовидном меню. Возможно в совсем "топорном" слайдере слайды обновляются через файлы, тогда там просто будет какая-то папочка со слайдами, работа примерно как с обычным файловым менеджером на хостинге.

Answer (score 1):

ModX это CMF система. Вам нужно искать всё исключительно внутри админки.
Смотрите в Элементы > Чанки | Элементы > Снипеты | Элементы > Шаблоны.

Answer (score 0):

Поищите чанк с названием slider(ну или что-то похожее). Там скорее всего и содержится код слайдера.